# ColdFusion / IIS / Redirect Limit?

Tags: iis, coldfusion, iis-8, coldfusion-10

I have a ColdFusion script which performs a task and then redirects to itself using the `<cflocation>` tag, passing in the next ID to be processed.  The script stops working after EXACTLY 51 rows.  I thought it was a bug in the code, so I updated the ID to be process to 52, and it runs from ID 52 through 102 and stops.  Again, 51 rows exactly.

does anyone know if there is some limit in ColdFusion on the `cflocation` tag?  Or could this be something IIS is doing?

When I use JavaScript `window.location` method, it works fine and does not stop until the end - as expected.

**Updated - Explanation**

The reason the script redirects to itself after each ID is processed is because ColdFusion does not release variables/memory back to the JVM until after the request is complete.  So, for a request that performs several hundred complicated tasks, the memory usage continues to grow until the request officially completes.  This causes an ERROR OUT OF MEMORY in the JVM.  From what I understand, the best way to correct this is to split the items out into separate requests, that way ColdFusion will release the request variables/memory back to the JVM.  Thus, why we are processing 1 item and then redirecting to self passing in the next ID to process.  This is to keep ColdFusion seeing the requests as unique and keep memory consumption down.

Comment: This sounds like it could be an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Instead of asking how to fix your attempted solution it may be helpful to tell us what the actual problem is that you are trying to fix by redirecting this many times?

Comment: @Miguel-F - updated my question to show more detail

Comment: I assume by passing an ID that you are updating, or somehow working with, records in a database?  Why are you storing so many things in memory? Can you re-use the same structures for each iteration? Can't you remove the structures between each iteration? AFAIK using `StructDelete()` will destroy references to those variables thus releasing the memory space for GC. Even if you get passed this redirect limitation tho I'm guessing you will start having issues with request timeouts next.

Comment: I'd agree with @Miguel-F here. This seems like an awful lot of work being done that may could be done in a better way. If your process is running the JVM out of memory, there's probably an issue with the way the process is working. I would also look into Leeish's suggestion of working with a queuing mechanism to process these records. But if it's possible to batch these processes rather than loop them, that would be better.

Comment: What sort of "several hundred complicated tasks" are you running on each iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an *"ugly hack"* but, maybe you'd like to try in case you can't find another option.

I was able to test and run this until completion as a scheduled task by executing `curl` from ColdFusion, so it requires `curl` available.

---

```
<cfparam name="url.id" default="0" />
<cfset url.id = url.id + 1 />


<!--- // your task code --->

<cffile 
    action = "append"
    file = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\foo\redir-log.txt" 
    output = '#url.id#'>

<!--- // your task code --->


<!--- // condition to end the loop --->
<cfif (url.id lt 300)>

    <cfset args = [
        'http://127.0.0.1:53227/redir.cfm?id=#url.id#'
    ] />

    <cfexecute 
        name="curl" 
        arguments="#args#" 
        variable="output" 
        errorVariable="error" 
        timeout="0" 
    />

    <cfdump var="#output#" />
    <hr />

    <cfdump var="#error#" />
    <hr />

</cfif>
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about a limit being there in ColdFusion/IIS, but I think browsers have a fail safe in order to restrict infinite loop. In my browser(Chrome), it seems the limit is 19.

The ways to overcome this is to make sure that the HTML loads, so that we do not confuse the session. Then redirect using either of the following.

1. `window.location`
2. `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://example.com">`.

Comment: Any suggestions as to how I can redirect from within a CF Scheduled Task?  I'm trying the meta tag (as JavaScript is not executed in scheduled tasks) but it's doing nothing.

Comment: If you are doing this via a scheduled task, maybe you'd be better going with a queue. So, create a scheduled task to repeat every 1 minute or something like that and run it at a certain time. Each time you run the task check your queue to see if there are more records in the queue. If there are none left, update the scheduled task to not run until the following night. I think you are possible hitting the redirect limit like RRK says.

Comment: Along the lines of what @Leeish said, if you're using a queue, there's no need to redirect in order to pass an ID to the next run. So you could just let the task continue to run every X minutes. On each run, it grabs the next ID from the queue and does its work. If there's nothing to process it'll just exit and wait until the next scheduled run.